# Switching on cases of `const` instance

Tags: dart

I am trying to switch on cases of `const` instances. Am I doing something wrong or isn't that possible at all in Dart?

```
Case expressions must have the same types, 'Foo.baz' isn't a 'Bar' - line 23
```

Example:

```
class Foo {
  const Foo();

  static const bar = Bar();
  static const baz = Baz();
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  const Bar() : super();
}

class Baz extends Foo {
  const Baz() : super();
}

void main() {
  Foo foo;

  switch (foo) {
    case Foo.bar:
      print(1);
      break;
    case Foo.baz:
      print(2);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with `const`.  What is your `switch` statement supposed to do?  Perhaps you could rewrite it using `if`-`else` first to demonstrate what outcome you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of Dart requires all switch case expressions to have the same type.
Yours have types `Bar` and `Baz`, which are different.

With the Null Safety language change, that requirement will go away, and the case expressions will just have to have a type which is a subtype of the `switch (e)` expression's type.

So, it's an error for now, but it will change in the future.